# Determine whether the given set of image of piecewise function as follow is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function with
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if} \ x \lt -1 \\
x^2+1, &\text{if} \ x \in [-1,1] \\
\frac{1}{2x}, &\text{if} \ x \gt 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

1. Is it true that the set $A=\{f(x) \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ bounded? Explain it.
2. Find the infimum and the supremum of the set $B = \{f(x)+2 \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$.

**Attempt:**
For $1$, the first think I do is to partition $f$ into three cases as follows.

**Case 1.** $x \in (-\infty,-1)$.
Let $C = \{f(x) \mid x \in (-\infty,-1)\}$.
By definition, $f$ is a constant (zero) function.
Then, $C = \{0\}$ and so, $C$ is bounded.

**Case 2.** $x \in [-1,1]$. Let $D = \{f(x) \mid x \in [-1,1]\}$. Then,
$D = [1,2]$ and so, $D$ is bounded.

**Case 3.** $x \in (1, \infty)$. Let $E = \{f(x) \mid x \in (1,\infty)\}$.
Then, $E = \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and so, $E$ is bounded.

Hence, from three cases above, we conclude that $A$ is bounded.

${}$

For $2$, notice that $B = \{2\} \cup [3,4] \cup \left(0,\frac{5}{2}\right)$. Hence, $\inf(B) = 0$ and $\sup(B) = 4$.

Am I true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct. Bu the other on is not. In fact, $B=\{2\}\cup[3,4]\cup\left(2,\frac52\right)$. Therefore, $\inf(B)=2$ and $\sup(B)=4$.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Nice Sir. Thanks!